# Is an OCR'ed word inverted (light text on dark background)?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Does Tesseract API provide a way to find out if a given OCR'ed word was inverted (light text on dark background) or not inverted (dark text on light background)? Or, more generally, to find out what the (roughly speaking) 'average' text and background colors are in a given word?